# Does Mozilla Firefox have a command palette?

Tags: firefox

###### Question

Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/experimental-features/edge-command-palette) in Microsoft Edge or in Google Chrome?

[image]

###### My research

I've googled for it but only found extensions that simulate some kind of command palette. But they all didn't provide Firefox commands, for example, like "Bookmark all tabs" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Firefox Quick Actions

In Firefox, you can enable something called Quick Actions. This feature is still being tested.

To enable it:

1. Navigate to `about:config` in the URL bar
2. Accept the Risk and Continue
3. Search for `browser.urlbar.quickactions.enabled`
4. If the preference exists, set it to `true`. If it does not exist, add it as a `Boolean` preference
   [image: Add preference]
5. Restart Firefox

Now you should be able to type `>`  in the URL bar and access Quick Actions.
[image: Quick Actions]

Comment: In Firefox v. 110.0.1, the current release as of your answer,  adding `browser.urlbar.quickactions.enabled`, whether as Boolean or String, makes no change in behavior of URL bar. Perhaps that is in *Beta*? BTW, *do* specify variable type.

Comment: I was able to enable it on 110.0.1, screenshots are from normal release, not Beta or Nightly. `Boolean` is default for me but good point, added.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the set of commands is rather limited. I.e. no tab control commands like 'close other tabs' etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Command palette addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/command-palette-for-firefox/) extension for Firefox has lot of actions like open tab, close tab, open in container tab, open in temporary tab, etc.

However, these are fixed actions and new actions from other extensions don't come up when you install the extensions.

For example, you can't toggle "Dark Reader" for current site.

[image: screenshot showing command palette]

[Another addon: Omni - Manage Tabs, Bookmarks, History](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/omnisearch/)